# Physical meaning of weight function in inner product in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

When taking the inner product of say two functions in Quantum Mechanics,we include a weight function w(x,y,z) that is usually equal to unity(in my undergraduate introductory QM course anyway). But when it is not equal to one, then it changes the outcome. So, what is the meaning of that function?

I tried to think of it in terms of vectors, saying that functions are vectors in infinite dimensions, so the inner product of functions is an integral rather than sum, but then again, i did not find any weight function in my linear algebra course during the process of taking the inner product between two vectors. Furthermore, it seems like it gives different weight to each dimension in the infinite dimensional vector space that QM takes place, so why would the inner product be taken in a way that some "axis"(if we can talk about axis), or dimensions if you prefer, play a bigger role in the inner product than other?

I seriously need an intuitive explanation here, thanks!

Comment: The weight function is usually an interaction that is missing from the Hamiltonian that generated the wave functions.  The result is a perturbation theory estimate of the contribution of the missing term to whatever is being calculated.

Comment: @Landos Check out the Sturm-Liouville theory of diff. eqs.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory. Most QM textbook examples reduce to some equation fitting the Sturm-Liouville ansatz, which in turn usually involves a nontrivial weight function.